# Having issue with delegate_to in playbook calling a role to only run on one host in a list

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, ansible-role

I have a playbook and only want to run this play on the first master node. I tried moving the list into the role but did not see to work. Thanks for your help!

```
## master node only changes
- name: Deploy change kubernetes Master
  remote_user: tyboard
  become: true
  roles:
  - role: gd.kubernetes.master.role
    files_location: ../files
  delegate_to: "{{ groups['masters'][0] }}"
```

ERROR! 'delegate_to' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/mnt/win/kubernetes.playbook/deploy-kubernetes.yml': line 11, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

### master node only changes

- name: Deploy change kubernetes Master
  ^ here

Answer (score 1):

In one playbook, [create a new group](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) with this host in the first play and use it in the second play. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: Create group with masters.0
  host: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ groups.masters.0 }}"
        groups: k8s_master_0

- name: Deploy change kubernetes Master
  hosts: k8s_master_0
  remote_user: tyboard
  become: true
  roles:
    - role: gd.kubernetes.master.role
      files_location: ../files
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

---

- Fix the [role name](https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/contributing/creating_role.html#role-names)
- If `files_location` is a variable which shall be used in the role's scope put it into the `vars`. For example

```yaml
  roles:
    - role: gd.kubernetes.master.role
      vars:
        files_location: ../files
```